# Пробелы в MySql запросах

Tags: mysql

Пробелы в MySql запросах

НЕ Работает

```
... WHERE `list` IN (1,5,7)
    GROUP BY `id` HAVING COUNT (`list`) = 3;
```

Работает

```
... WHERE `list` IN (1,5,7)
    GROUP BY `id` HAVING COUNT(`list`) = 3;
```

Разница в пробеле после COUNT между скобкой.
Почему так?

Comment: НИГДЕ не допускается пробел между именем функции и обрамляющими список её параметров скобками...

Comment: Почему тогда игнориуется пробел перед IN и всё работает? И если не трудно ссылку про пробел на документацию MySql

Comment: IN - **НЕ** функция.

Answer (score 0):

НИГДЕ не допускается пробел между именем функции и обрамляющими список её параметров скобками.

IN - НЕ функция.

Спасибо:  Akina